# PRAWN Setting a different font size for fallback_fonts

Tags: fonts, prawn

Is there a way to set a different font size for the `fallback_fonts` in Prawn? For example, I'd like my default font to be 8.5 and the `fallback_fonts` to be 6.

```
font("RobotoBoldCondensed") do
  text_box "Some text",
  :size => 8.5,
  :font => "Helvetica",
      (:fallback_fonts => fallback_fonts, :size => 6)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Prawn. But one way to make sure a font is available is by creating a object containing a string of text set in the font you want to test. Than measure the size of the object. If the font is loaded, the object will have some expected size. If the font isn't loaded, you can switch to fallback font and apply the alternative font size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question was specific to Prawn, which I doesn't support JS.

Comment: Aie! I overlooked the tag and didn't pay enough attention to your code.